# Word count program printing different counts

Tags: c

I am trying to count the words, lines, characters, vowels, case etc.. from a .txt file and I am getting varying results.. When I am purely counting for lines and characters it prints out the correct result. But when I add in the counts for uppercase and lowercase it prints out a massive count for lines and character (e.g. 32974). I'm guessing there is an error with my logic? Thankyou.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int nextChar = getchar();

    int lines, characters, uppercase,lowercase;

    while (nextChar != EOF)
    {
        if (isalpha(nextChar) || isblank(nextChar) || ispunct(nextChar))
        {
            characters++;
        } else if (isspace(nextChar)){
            characters++;
            lines++;
        }

        if(isalpha(nextChar) && isupper(nextChar)){
            uppercase++;
        } else if (isalpha(nextChar) && islower(nextChar)){
            lowercase++;
        }
        nextChar = getchar();
    }
    printf("%d lines\n",lines);
    printf("%d characters\n",characters);
    printf("%d lowercase\n",lowercase);
    printf("%d uppercase\n",uppercase);
}
```

Comment: `int lines, characters, uppercase,lowercase;` Mind initializing your variables?

Comment: Thankyou,  so simple I don't know how i missed it. I was too focused on the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the counts to `0`. Otherwise you program will be ill formed (will invoke undefined behavior).

```
int lines = 0, characters = 0, uppercase = 0,lowercase = 0;
```